# can externally loaded website access cordova javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have a website in place and I would like to load it into a webview giving the site a native feel.

Now, this is fairly simple to do using window.location='url' but when the site loads the javascript on the site is not able to access plugin apis. So it seems the site is running within a sandbox... unable to access cordova apis.

Is there a way to provide an externally loaded website access to the cordova apis?

I load my external site using `<content src="http://myurl"/>` in my config.xml

Comment: Another suggestion is not to load your site as the main starting file. Because of the large number of files phonegap takes, it can take a really long time for the first page to display. I would use the normal local index.html and in it on deviceready, load your site with top.location.href=... What I do is start on a loader page with a progress bar that uses ajax to load every js and css file the site needs. That way from then on, everything is cached and all the pages load fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. Upload all the cordova.js and plugin files from the project to your server, then in the pages on your server just include it. Be sure to keep them in the same relative folders as they are in the project.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

(Note that I have done this on versions 3 to 5, but not in 6 yet.)

Comment: I find this to be a hacky way to do this but seems to be the only way. It would be nice if Cordova would give a webview access to the API directly. This would most likely cause other problems when loading assets in a webview.

Comment: One thing I forgot to add is that the files are different between platforms, so you need to upload all them for the various platforms. Also if you upgrade your Phonegap version, you need to upload the new files, but keep the old ones on your server for people using previous versions of the app. It's a bit of a mess, but I just have different folders like ios.5.5.1, android.4.1.0 etc and then put all the files for each version in them. When I load the website from the app I include the platform and version in the query string then drop a cookie so that it loads the right one on every page.

Comment: Which files would need to be uploaded, though? I see multiple `cordova.js` files in the `platforms/android` directory (and its children) alone